# Android studio enviar zip con gmail

Tags: android, email, zip

estoy intentando enviar por correo un archivo zip y cuando esta cargando el cuerpo del correo me dice, "no se ha podido adjuntar el archivo"

He probado diferentes formas de obtener la url, pero no consigo que lo encuentre.

Estoy utilizando, Sdk Version 28 y min 26,

Aqui creo el archivo

```
public static void panicButtonCompression(Context context, String folderToZip, String zipFileName) {
    int BUFFER = 2048;

    File folder = new File(getAbsPath(context, folderToZip));
    File zipFile = new File(getAbsPath(context, ""), zipFileName);
    File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();

    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream origin;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

            for (File file : fileList) {
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;

                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                origin.close();
            }

            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Crashlytics.log(Log.ERROR, "Tools|panicButtonCompression", "panicButtonCompression error: " + e.toString());
        }

        emergencySending(context, zipFileName);
    }
}
```

Y aqui envio el correo.

```
private static void emergencySending(Context context, String zipFileName) {
    String filePath = new File(getAbsPath(context, "")) + zipFileName;
    Uri path = Uri.parse(filePath);
    String to[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.emailsForEmergencySending);
    String subject = context.getResources().getString(R.string.email_default_subject);
    String text = context.getResources().getString(R.string.email_default_text);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("application/zip");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);



    if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        context.startActivity(emailIntent );
    }
}
```

No se si sera por la version del sdk que me falta algo o gmail lo bloquea.

Gracias.

Comment: Viendo el código yo diria que no lo adjuntas realmente.

Comment: @JDev acabo de hacer un cambio, que habia copiado una parte que no era la correcta. No se si cambia tu respuesta con esto nuevo.

Comment: Ahora si se añade.

Comment: He vuelto a intentar solucionarlo y me dice lo mismo, cuando esta dentro de la aplicacion de gmail, añade todo, titulo, cuerpo del mensaje, pero el archivo me dice, No se ha podido adjuntar el archivo.
¿Necesitas permisos en gmail para enviar un zip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale ya lo he resuelto, lo que pasa es que ahora con sdk > 24, necesitas utilizar FileProvider. Y de esta forma el archivo zip si se adjunta.

La clase principal tiene que extender de FileProvider

```
    private static void emergencySending(Context context, File zipFileName) {
    String to[] = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.emailsForEmergencySending);
    String subject = context.getResources().getString(R.string.email_default_subject);
    String text = context.getResources().getString(R.string.email_default_text);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("*/*");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);

    Uri file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +".provider", zipFileName);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file);
    context.startActivity(emailIntent);
}
```

También se necesita añadir varias cosas, al manifest y crear un archivo xml

Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Y en el archivo provider_paths en carpeta xml, si no la tenéis creadla, añadís esta linea entre las etiquetas, PreferenceScreen

```
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```